# NSNumber equivalence error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, for-loop, nsnumber

I'm trying to find beacons in range and sort UITableViewCells hereafter.
I am trying this;

```
NSLog(@"Trying (%@ = %@,  %@ = %@)",major, beacon1.major,minor, beacon1.minor);


        if(beacon1.major == major && beacon1.minor == minor){
            NSLog(@"%@;%@ is first",major,minor);
            [room insertObject:room atIndex:0];

        }
```

This means that if NSNumber Major and NSNumber Minor are equal to found beacon, the if will be run.
NSLog Retuns this:

```
2015-01-02 12:33:02.277 App[468:30045] Trying (47566000 = 47566,  39534000 = 39534)
2015-01-02 12:33:02.278 App[468:30045] Trying (47566000 = 47566,  39534000 = 39534)
2015-01-02 12:33:02.279 App[468:30045] Trying (47566 = 47566,  39534 = 39534)
```

I would hereafter expect it to run the third time. But it does not.

Do anyone have a clue whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing for variable instance equality, not the contained values.

Use isEqualToNumber: instead. [See documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/isEqualToNumber:).

The code should look like this:

```
if ([beacon1.major isEqualToNumber:major] && [beacon1.minor isEqualToNumber:minor]) {
    ...
}
```